# Docker ENOTFOUND при npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, docker

Почему при выполнении `npm i` я начинаю получать сообщения вида:

```
npm info attempt registry request try #2 at 11:45:00 PM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis
npm info attempt registry request try #2 at 11:45:00 PM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hiredis
npm info attempt registry request try #2 at 11:45:00 PM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
```

Answer (score 3):

Помог перезапуск службы docker
`sudo service docker restart`

Видимо DNS нужно было обновить